# Execution of asynchronous code in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am relatively new to `nodejs` development. I need to execute a function asynchronously doing some unimportant stuff, that's the reason I want to do it asynchronously like recording the no. of calls this method has received. The recording part is not super critical to me and does not want it to hinder or slow down the main flow in anyway.

I have considered using `return Promise` like this:

```
return new Promise( /* executor */ function(resolve, reject) { ... } );
```

But observed that the executor starts executing immediately, as mentioned in the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)( Not sure about it though.).

I am not interested in this behavior because then some computations of the `executor` function will be running before my normal flow(the caller function) could continue. I know I should not keep the sync portion computationally intensive, and I have not kept it intensive.

Pseudo code for the my flow looks something like this:

```
export let mainFunc = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
     // logic for handling the request is here
     // need to record analytic information here by calling
     recordInformation(req);
}


function recordInformation(req){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        //some synchronous code followed by asynchronous code
    });
}
```

Just that I am looking out for a way such that the calling function `mainFunc` never waits for even a single computation after calling `recordInformation`.

Comment: What do you mean by run asynchronously? If you use a synchronous operation inside your promise, then that will be synchronous. But the promise itself is running "asynchronously" because where it was returned continues to run in "parallel"

Comment: If you have compute intensive code that you want to run in the background, promises will not help with that. Any compute-heavy code will still block the main thread, even if it's wrapped within a promise. I would advise looking into [Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker) because they're precisely for running background operations.

Comment: @Bill By asynchronous I want the promise to be executed asynchronously.  When I tested it on my machine, the promise `executor` part executed before the next statement of the calling function. I understand it can happen in async environment. But when I checked in Mozilla docs also, it states that `The executor function is executed immediately by the Promise implementation`. That's the reason I am confused if the executor part running asynchronously or not.

Comment: @JLRishe It's not compute intensive tasks, therefore not looking for alternatives. But thanks for the suggestion, I didn't know about Workers.

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja Ok, in that case I'm not sure what value you're looking to obtain from promises. Can you give a clearer example?

Comment: Promises are intended for async actions... think of making an http request. If you put this is the promise executor, yes it's executed right away but while you are waiting for the response, your other statements will be running. You really need to explain what you are trying to achieve for us to help more. Why do you need it to be asynchronous?

Comment: @Bill Edited the question to include more explanation of what I want to achieve.

Comment: Why not just execute this unimportant recording function after you've done everything else?

Comment: If you could show us some more code, even psuedo-code, just to show the flow of the main script and the async portion, that would help a lot

Comment: @Bill I can do it at the end, but it won't solve the problem. I want to avoid having any delay in response of my API request(the function is called in API request). I have edited the question also to include pseudo code to explain my situation better.

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja _"Just that I am looking out for a way such that the calling function mainFunc never waits for even a single computation after calling recordInformation."_ The example in my answer does achieve this goal, but be aware that any synchronous code within the function passed into `then` will _eventually_ block the main thread when it eventually runs (after the execution control has gone back to the host). That's why I suggested workers.

Comment: @JLRishe I know your answer provides one such solution which fulfils the requirement. I have already upvoted the answer. Just waiting of Bill has any better alternate. 
I understand it will eventually block the main thread when it runs. If my use case grows I will definitely look out for workers.

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja Ok. :) Just wanted to make sure it was perfectly clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as the MDN docs state, the function passed into `new Promise()` is executed synchronously.

Example:

```js
function temp() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('This runs right away');
  });
}

temp();
temp();
temp();
console.log('This runs last');
```

If you want to run some code asynchronously, pass it into a `.then()`:

```js
function temp() {
    return Promise.resolve().then(function () {
        console.log('This runs later');
    });
}

temp();
temp();
temp();
console.log('This runs right away');
```

Bear in mind that if all you want to do is have some code run after the current execution stack has finished, then a simple `setTimeout` could probably be just as good:

```js
function temp() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('This runs later');
    }, 1);
}

temp();
temp();
temp();
console.log('This runs right away');
```

Comment: `function temp(){  
     return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){ 
                                                console.log("Hello")
                           })}`. Does the following code print `Hello` synchronously whenever the temp function is called?

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja Yes, it does.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. Can you please add this in the answer as well, along with may be a explanation why it does execute synchronously or a better resource to refer so as to why is this the behavior.

Comment: @Bill Would you care to elaborate on how it is misleading and bordering on plain wrong?

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja My answer already says that the function passed into `new Promise()` is executed synchronously. You are passing a function into `new Promise()`, so that function will be executed synchronously.

Comment: Yes, it does execute immediately and synchronously. But chaining on a `.then` is a hack, it's unreliable, and doesn't help the OP understand the problem

Comment: @Bill I've already done my best to explain the problem to OP and ask for clarification in the comments under his question. All I can do at this point is answer the question he asked. In what way is chaining on `.then` a "hack and unreliable"?

Comment: You said yourself that you're not sure what value he is trying to get from using promises - if you aren't sure what he's trying to achieve how can you possibly provide a valuable answer? I think this is clearly an XY problem where what the OP is asking is not quite what he needs to be asking. Let me put it this way; can you think of any scenario where you would actually do that? (`Promise.resolve().then(() => {})`)? Given that you understand promises, you would never do that, it's pointless. And it's an unreliable hack because it relies on order of execution which is not guaranteed.

Comment: @Bill I am OK with the solution provided in the thread, I want exactly this behavior.  It'd be great if you have an alternative way to achieve the same in some more cleaner way.(or some preferred approach)

Comment: This solution is roughly equivalent to `setTimeout(executor, 1)` (which I don't think is what you're going for)

Comment: @Bill Yes, there are absolutely valid situations where I would use `Promise.resolve().then(...)` (though not quite like the example above). And the code inside the `.then()` _is guaranteed_ to run asynchronously, i.e. after the current execution stack has cleared. That means it would absolutely execute after the `console.log('This runs right away')`.

Comment: @JLRishe afaik `Promise.resolve().then()` would be exactly the same as `new Promise()`.
> "And the code inside the .then() is guaranteed to run asynchronously, i.e. after the current execution stack has cleared." - could you please provide a reference for this as afaik that isn't correct?

Comment: @Bill [Promises/A+ spec, section 2.2.4](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-34), my friend. And no, passing a function into `then()` is _nothing_ like passing one into `new Promise()`.

Comment: @Bill I've now clarified with OP beyond a shadow of a doubt that this is precisely what they were looking to do, and provided evidence that it is, in fact, not "unreliable" as you previously stated. Wanna undo that downvote?

Answer (score 0):

From your pesudo-code; you can respond to the request, then call you other function after that. This would mean that all of your request handling including the response is executed before your other function:

```
export let mainFunc = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
     // logic for handling the request is here
     res.end('Hello World');
     // response is now sent, feel free to do anything else at your leisure..
     // need to record analytic information here by calling
     recordInformation(req);
}


function recordInformation(req){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        //some synchronous code followed by asynchronous code
    });
}
```